# how nodejs socket.on('data' works?

Tags: json, node.js, sockets, tcp

how nodejs **socket.on('data'** works without end of line at the end of data ?

I mean how nodejs separate every data without any separator like \n

this question is because I found a little bug in my script

the bug is :

when sending data very fast , all data will be attached to one and socket.on('data' will run only once

for example

in client side :

if sending two or mode data at same time (on same open connection) like this :

```
client.write('1');
client.write('2');
```

on the server **socket.on('data'** will be called once and data will be 12

and this will get error if sendig json data

Comment: That's the expected behavior. You're receiving the data that you sent and a separator was not part of it. If you want you can add a separator yourself and parse it on the other side. Or use a 3rd party software to manage that for you.

Comment: tnx , see the solution blow

Answer (score 0):

finally I found the solution

since in nodejs tcp sockets , every chunk not contain previous chunk
this trick would 100 percent work !

server :

```
socket.on('data', function (data) {

    var newdata = ""+data;
    var newdatachunks = newdata.split("\n");

         for (var i = 0 ; i<(newdatachunks.length-1);i++) {
             console.log("real data is :"+newdatachunks[i]); 
         }

});
```

client :

in client side every message **must** finish with \n (or any separator you like)

```
client.write("1\n");
client.write("2\n");
client.write("3\n");
client.write("4\n");
```

**notice** : and if you work with json dont forget use try/catch